# Facebook login integration with Android app

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I am trying to integrate Facebook login with my Android app. As I click on the login button, it launches Facebook login page then another window "your have already authorized myapp". Here, as I click on OK, it takes me back to my app's last view and nothing is happening and it's not getting any callback of Loginmanager.

I am referring to this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android and following all the steps like

Generate development key, App id , update build.gradle file, manifeast file, etc.

I have tried all the things and got struck badly. I tried all solutions from Google search but problem is intact.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyAccountFragment extends BaseFragment {

    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    final String TAG = "MyAccountFragment";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private static  int count = 0;

    private final List<String> permissions;
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
    public static MyAccountFragment fragment;

    public MyAccountFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
        permissions = Arrays.asList("user_status","public_profile", "user_friends");
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment LoginFragment.
     */
    //TODO: Check if you need multiple instances of this class or single.
    public static MyAccountFragment getInstance(String param1, String param2) {

        if(count == 0) {
             fragment = new MyAccountFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            count++;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        Boolean fbDebugFlag = true;

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
        FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(fbDebugFlag);//to do " only for debug app
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // App code
                        Profile currentProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "name"+currentProfile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "first name"+currentProfile.getFirstName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Logger.debug(TAG, "***********loginResponse: " + currentProfile.getFirstName());

                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {
                                        // Application code
                                        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "response"+ response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onError", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        try {
            PackageInfo info = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.android.fameincity",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error: NameNotFoundException", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error: NoSuchAlgorithmException", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


        mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(
                    Profile oldProfile,
                    Profile currentProfile) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "name"+currentProfile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "first name"+currentProfile.getFirstName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myaccount, container, false);
       TextView fbLogin = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.facebook);


        fbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MyAccountFragment.this, permissions);

            }
        });

        return view ;
    }

    @Override
     public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
    }
}
```

I am aware of the fact that if use Fragment then OnActivityResult will be called of Activity then direct this to Fragment's OnActivityResult. So I am getting the Fragment's OnActivity result but not Loginmanager call back.

Please help me as I am completely clueless here.

Comment: So you never getting onSuccess toast message? If not, what toast messages are you getting?

Comment: yes not getting any of the callback like OnSuccess, OnCancel, OnError

Comment: Try to print the result code and print it here. This might be a permissions problem, but it should go to onError or onSuccess. You might want to put 'this' instead of 'getActivity()' in your Toast Messages. I doubt that will help, but it's weird these toast messages aren't coming.

Comment: Usually people put Log.d or Log.e instead of toast messages.

Comment: I tried after removing this line super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); but there is no change . Yes I have used Log.d to print these two values  requestCode: 129742   resultCode: -1

Comment: -1 Usually means RESULT_OK. Make sure you put Log statements on the first line of onSuccess, onError, or onCancel. Try to change permissions to just be public_profile. You might want to simplify code to just be like the facebook example.

Comment: tried as suggested by you.... not getting callback logs

Comment: Time do debugger. Put the breakpoint onActivityResult

Comment: It's showing you all your variables, and the fact that callbackmanager is not null is good, so it should go to one of those functions. Also put break points in all the onSuccess/Cancel/Error fucntions and LoginManager lines just to follow where you code is going.

Comment: Not going anywhere in callback ...exit ....getting message in debugger window "Frame is not available"

Comment: cant anyone help me here

Comment: Message me in a chat?

Comment: sorry , I didn't get you. What should I message you?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: not able to do bcaz of less point I do have in my account :(

Comment: Why are you using a base fragment? Any specific reason?

Comment: yes, project is already using it so this is the default choice cant change it.

Comment: is there anything which I can try ?

Comment: I would try this on the sample projects available on [github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/) with the latest SDK and see if that work for you, if so, then you need to take it from there.